# How to retrieve an array from Firebase Firestore and output it onto an HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, cloud

I have an array with multiple objects in it. I would like to output the objects onto an HTML page

[image]

The image above is how the array is structured. There is an array called reserved items and it has objects in it. I would like to output all the objects in this array, specifically the "Title" element.
here is the code I tried using

```
let query;
    if (lastReservedBook != null) {
        query = db.collection("users").where("uid", "==", uid).startAfter(lastReservedBook)
    } else {
        query = db.collection("users").where("uid", "==", uid);
    }
    
    query.limit(100).get().then(querySnapshot=>{
    
        lastReservedBook = querySnapshot.docs[querySnapshot.docs.length - 1];
    
            querySnapshot.forEach(doc=>{
            console.log(doc.data())
            let data = doc.data();
            let row  = `<tr>
                                    <td><a onclick="barcode=${data.Barcode}; myFunction(this)">${data.reserved_items}</a></td>
                                    
                            </tr>`;
            let table = document.getElementById('myTable')
            table.innerHTML += row
            document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none"
            })
        })
        .catch(err=>{
            console.log(`Error: ${err}`)
        });
```

This is the output (which I don't want):
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are mixing up the documents and the fields.

Making the assumption user IDs (i.e. `uid`) are unique, the query on `db.collection("users").where("uid", "==", uid)` will **return only one document**.

Then, in this unique document, you have a field named `reserved_items` which is of type [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). More precisely it is an Array of Objects. So you need to loop over the Array elements, not on the [`QuerySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot).

So the following should do the trick:

```
  let query = db.collection('users').where('uid', '==', uid);

  query
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
      const queryDocumentSnapshot = querySnapshot.docs[0]; //There is only one doc in the QuerySnapshot!!

      const reservedItemsArray = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
        .reserved_items;

      reservedItemsArray.forEach((obj, index) => {
        let row = `<tr><td><a onclick="barcode=${obj.Barcode}; myFunction(index)">${obj.Title}</a></td></tr>`;
        table.innerHTML += row;
      });

      // ...
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(`Error: ${err}`);
    });
```

It's not 100% clear to me:

- What you want to display for the link text... I've used the `Title` with `obj.Title` but you may adapt.
- What you want to do with `myFunction(this)`. You should probably use the `index`, e.g. like `myFunction(index)`, which indicates the position of the element in the Array.
- Why you limit to 100. It's up to you to adapt the above code if you only want to display 100 lines in the table. But again, if you need to limit the number of elements to be displayed, this limit shall apply to the elements of the Array, not to the query.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. How do I make this solution work for multiple documents? querySnapshot.docs[querySnapshot.docs.length];

Comment: You should loop over the QuerySnapshot, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
console.log(JSON.stringfy(doc.data()));
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(doc.data()) , this shall work if the issue is that you are not seeing the data in the object ( you might need a loop )